# automatically delete pods on Openshift once completed

Tags: openshift

I have an application that starts many pods on Openshift, and since we have very limited resources, I wanted to know if there is a way to automatically delete a pod once it's completed, since it seems I can't find anywhere.
I know it would be much easier not to start that many pods (hundreds), but unfortunately for me, it's not something I can have a saying in it.
Thank you

Comment: How are you creating them? Are you using a Job/CronJob, creating Pods directly, or using a deployment of some sort?

Comment: Yes, we are using a job reading from a json with all the information to create those pods, and not using a deployment.

Comment: Just to clarify, when you say job, you mean you are creating a Kubernetes ``Job`` resource, not creating the ``Pod`` yourself? If creating a ``Job``, it is upon you to delete the remaining ``Job`` resource after having read back the completion status of the job. If you are using a ``Job`` and the pod exits, there will not be a ``Pod`` left around.

Answer (score 0):

oc delete pod --field-selector=status.phase==Succeeded --all-namespaces